# Getting pain while concentrating on Ajna Chakra

Tags: rama, meditation, chakras, mudra, nama-japa

I've been trying to concentrate on my ajna chakra while meditating. I'm doing Sri Ram naama japa with one hand while holding chinmudra with the other. I had a sensation suddenly to concentrate on Ajna Chakra (Forehead/mainly focusing between my eyes). I don't know why but I'm getting a little pain of some sort at the point I'm concentrating. I've googled about it some are saying that I'm about to open my third eye and others are claiming might be blocked at some other chakra so stop meditating on it. Which should I believe and how should I proceed further?

Comment: Are you doing meditation under the guidance of any Guru?

Comment: No I've been practicing all my spiritual stuff by myself.